# Stop SD card from constantly unmounting due to underpowered

Tags: sd-card, battery-life

I had problems with constant unmounting of my SD card from phone when it was not on charger. The problem was with powering off some power when disabling display to save energy, but this power was needed to keep SD card mounted.

My phone is LG Optimus L1 II E410, but from what I found during my long search for solution, it is not the only phone affected.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: How to prevent SD card from unmounting? LOL. Maybe you didn't notice I made it QandA style question, just because I lost like 5 hours to find the solution and thought it would be helpful to have it in some place where people would look for it.

Comment: So why is that wakelock app needed at all? What's causing the unmount to happen? I never encountered that on any device. Did you apply some "freaky" power-saving stuff?

Comment: What is this bit "*problem was with powering off some power when disabling display to save energy*"? Have you set it to disable other components when the screen turns off, or is this just something that you've spotted happening?

Comment: It is original, not rooted system with no special settings, so this is just something that I found out that was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install program [Wake Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl) and set the setting to `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. This keep necessary power for SD card even if of charger and with disabled display. It obviously cause a bit more battery consumption, but far less then constant SD card remounting. No root needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Alcatel POP C5 with Kingston 8GB micro SD class-10 card. First, I thought that the problem was with the phone. After replacing with another, borrowed card, the phone was working normal again, so I concluded that it was the bad SD card.

Using [Wake Lock - PowerManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.wl) with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` enabled did solve the problem, partialy. I wanted the permanent solution so I keep trying to solve the problem.

The first time I realized the card was unmounting, when phone was on standby, was this summer when outside temperatures exceeded 35°C. I thought if hot temperature caused the problem, it might be also the solution to it.

First, I took my soldering iron and heat all MicroSD card metal contacts for approximately 10 seconds. After that, the phone was not unmounting the card for 20-30 minutes, but then it started showing error messages again. Then, I heated each contact, once more, for 2 minutes. The card was too hot to touch it with my hand, and I was worried not to melt the plastic. After that intervention, the card did not melt, all of the data was still on it and the card is working in my phone for 2 days now, without unmounting.

I hope that this is a permanent solution and that will help someone else too.

Just to say that *I am not responsible if someone damage their card or data attempting to do this*. **DO IT AT YOUR OWN RISK!**